# Modeless Child Dialog

Tags: winapi, class, dialog

I'm creating modeless child dialogs from a parent dialog class and i want to share the class data of its parent window with all child dialog classes I'll be creating. how would i go do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by class data?  The WindowClass or a pointer to your class that implements the parent?  And how are you creating the child dialog (what API call)?

Comment: I want to access the functions of parent class into child class and i'm creating the child dialog by creating an instance of child class inside parent class which uses CreateDialog API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use [SetWindowLongPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898(VS.85).aspx):

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndParent, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)&parent_class);
```

This will set the USERDATA field on the parent hwnd to be the address of the parent class.  Then in your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler, call `GetWindowLongPtr()` on your parent HWND and cast it back to the correct pointer type.

A **better** way to do it is to use [CreateDialogParam()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645445(v=VS.85).aspx) and in your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler you'll get the value you pass in the `dwInitParam` field, which would be the pointer to your parent class.